# QIcon not being displayed on QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning how to use Qt for C++ programming. I have this image I want to display after when I click at a button and the position on a matrix related to that button is equal to -1, I also want to clear the text on that same button, my code up to now for that part is:

```
if(Tabuleiro[x][y] == -1){
    this->Botoes[x][y]->setText("");
    this->Botoes[x][y]->setIcon(QIcon("bomba.png"));
}
```

Being that `Tabuleiro` is a matrix of int, `Botoes` is a matrix of pointers to QPushButtons and "bomba.png" is the image I want to display. The image is in the same folder as the project, but once I run it is not displayed. I also tryed using Qt Resource system, I created a new resource called imagens.qrc on it I created a prefix `/Imagem` and placed my image there, this is what the code looked like after this:

```
if(Tabuleiro[x][y] == -1){
        this->Botoes[x][y]->setText("");
        this->Botoes[x][y]->setIcon(QIcon(":/Imagem/bomba.png"));
    }
```

But it still won't work. What am I doing wrong? Also, I tryed using

```
this->Botoes[x][y]->text().clear();
```

instead of

```
this->Botoes[x][y]->setText("");
```

But it didn't work, do you know why?

Comment: Make sure the PNG in the working directory of your application (where executable is).

Comment: @Archie working directory is not the same thing as executable directory

Comment: @joão-areias consider using Qt resource system http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: Thanks Archie, it wasn't but that still didn't solve it

Comment: Thanks @KamilKlimek I just tried using Qt resource but still didn't work :(

Comment: On Windows in Qt Creator, the default working directory is not the one where the executable is, but the one where you chose to compile (usually one directory up).
For Qt resources to work, you need to execute qmake.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong

Comment: @JoãoAreias Try following one of these articles: [programatic way](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-customize-button-in-qt.html), [stylesheet way](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-add-stylesheet-for-button-in-qt.html).
Also if you used [Qt resource system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) try deleting output directory and recompiling entire project. Clean sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: @KamilKlimek I just edited the code above to show how it's looking right now with the resource file, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And how about your resource file? Did you create one? Did you add it to the pro file?

Comment: @KamilKlimek Yes, still not working but I found out why. My antivirus keeps blocking some of my softwares to access other file and QT was one of it, I have already configured it to allow qt and this program I made to access other files

Answer (score 3):

Please include `<QApplication>` and `<QStyle>` and try:

```
this->Botoes[x][y]->setIcon( qApp->style()->standardIcon( QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning ) );
```

If it works (warning icon being displayed): then, it means you're not loading your resources correctly.

You can also check this:

```
QPixmap foo( ":/Imagem/bomba.png" );
bool found = !foo.isNull(); // true if png file was found, false if it was not
```

If false, again, it means you're not loading your resources correctly, if true, icon should be displayed in the button.

Morevover, you can also try `this->Botoes[x][y]->setIconSize( QSize(16,16) )` because if someone earlier did `this->Botoes[x][y]->setIconSize( QSize(0,0) );` your button icon will not be displayed!

Comment: So b should be true is the png was found? that's weird I thought it would be false since there is something on foo and it's not null. But thanks, I'm messing up when loading the resources  since the Icon shows up

Comment: My mistake, I edited the post. `isNull` means png was not found.